# How change the spiral movement in 2D space?

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, spiral

I have two points in 2D space as we can see in the figure to move from the blue point to the red points we can use the equation (1). Where b is a constant used to limit the shape of the logarithmic spiral, l is a random number in [−1,1], which is used to
control the indentation effect of the movement, D indicates the distance between blue points and the current point

[image]

I need another movement that can move from blue points to the red points like in the figure

[image]

Comment: Your hand drawing is too imprecise to give a valuable answer. Please give a written description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sinusoidal model.

For start point `(X0, Y0)` and end point `(X1,Y1)` we have vector end-start, determine it's length - distance between points `L`, and angle of vector `Fi` (using `atan2`).

Then generate sinusoidal curve for some standard situation - for example, along OX axis, with magnitude `A`, `N` periods for distance `2 * Pi * N`:

Scaled sinusoid in intermediate point with parameter `t`, where `t` is in range `0..1` (t=0 corresponds to start point `(X0,Y0)`)

```
X(t) = t * L
Y(t) =  A * Sin(2 * N * Pi * t)
```

Then shift and rotate sinusoid using `X` and `Y` calculated above

```
X_result = X0 + X * Cos(Fi) - Y * Sin(Fi)
Y_result = Y0 + X * Sin(Fi) + Y * Cos(Fi)
```

Example Python code:

```
import math
x0 = 100
y0 = 100
x1 = 400
y1 = 200
nperiods = 4
amp = 120
nsteps = 20
leng = math.hypot(x1 - x0, y1 - y0)
an = math.atan2(y1 - y0, x1 - x0)
arg =  2 * nperiods* math.pi
points = []
for t in range(1, nsteps + 1):
    r = t / nsteps
    xx = r * leng
    yy =  amp * math.sin(arg * r)
    rx = x0 + xx * math.cos(an) - yy * math.sin(an)
    ry = y0 + xx * math.sin(an) + yy * math.cos(an)
    points.append([rx, ry])
print(points)
```

Draw points:

[image]

Comment: I didn't understand ou idea, mostly when you changed the variable name. What is t, X(t), and Y(t)?

Comment: yes, in my formula t is the next iteration whereas in your formula means other things, it's right? Otherwise, i am a beginner with such a problem, for that, i didn't understand the explanation brother. So, can you explain how i can go from my equation to your equation?

Comment: We can say that at your picture t changes with step 1. You cannot go from your equation, this is just another equation. It is possible to calculate the next point from the previous one, but it is more complex. Look at Python code

Comment: In my equation: `X(t+1)=[xi yi]`, so `X(t+1)` is a vector that contains the coordinate of the point in the iteration t+1, if i take your both results equations can we combine them in one equation? I don't know if i well explain the problem

Comment: OK, t is number of point now  in given code. Result list contains coordinates.

Comment: that's is nice, thank you very much, brother. this algorithm can be transformed to work on n-dimensional space?

Comment: Yes. Simple if you need such path in the plane. A bit more complex if you need something like 3D spiral (spring)